# Django sitemaps, two pages using the same object

Tags: django, sitemap

I am trying to add a sitemap to a jobsite I have built (first time using the sitemaps framework in Djnago, so not 100% sure what I should be doing).

Anyway, I have two pages, a "job detail" page, and a "job apply" page. These are both based on the Job model, and have urls referencing the job id.

urls.py

```
url(r'^job-details/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.JobDetailView.as_view(), name='job_detail' ) ,
url(r'apply/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.JobApplyView.as_view(), name='job_apply'  ),
```

sitemap.py

```
class JobsSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "daily"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Job.objects.filter( active=True,
                               venue__contacts__account_verified=True,
                               date_expires__gte=date.today())

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.date_posted
```

models.py

```
class Job(models.Model):
    ... field definitions here ....

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('job_detail',  kwargs={'pk': self.id})
```

Now the problem is that I have already specified get_absolute_url() on the Job model to point to the job detail page. So I can't point it to the job_apply page as well.

I tried configuring it according to the "Sitemap for static views" section in the docs, but that complains that there is no reverse match for that URL (as it is expecting the kwargs argument).

What is the correct way to deal with pages based on the same object?

Comment: add a new method to your model called get_apply_url and return the job_apply url or use {% url  "job_apply" job.pk %} in your template

Comment: That doesn't help, as I am not using any template, just the default one for sitemaps.xml, and looking at that, it doesn't call get_absolute_url - it has a set of urls passed to it. get_absolute_url() is called by django code, not my own.

Comment: You can define your own CustomSitemap class which inherits from sitemaps.Sitemap and override location method.

Comment: Ok, it seems that all I need to do is use teh location method to supply the reversed url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There maybe other ways of doing it, but one that's really simple is to create two SiteMaps. Let the current one be as it is and create a new one, this time make sure to override the `[location][1]` property.

> Location Optional. Either a method or attribute.
>
> If it’s a method, it should return the absolute path for a given
>   object as returned by items().
>
> If it’s an attribute, its value should be a string representing an
>   absolute path to use for every object returned

```
class JobsApplySitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "daily"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Job.objects.filter( active=True,
                               venue__contacts__account_verified=True,
                               date_expires__gte=date.today())

    def location(self, obj):
        return "/apply/{0}/".format(obj.pk) 
        # you can use reverse instead


    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.date_posted
```

Comment: I just discovered this by myself, before I saw your post, but this looks like the correct way to do it.

Comment: Sorry I couldn't post this a few minutes earlier.